# problem about vehicle routing problem by Gurobi Python

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, vehicle-routing, operations-research

I have a vehicle routing problem solved by linear programming, but I'm confused about the constraints of it (see the model on figure 1). in the model, u and x are decision variables, and we set node 0 as the depot, nodes 1 to n as customers. constraints 1 & 2 indicate that there can only be one edge for both going into and out of the CUSTOMER nodes. However when I use Gurobi optimizer to solve it,  I find the solution always includes the depot (node 0) in (see a solution on figure 2). Even I set the depot to an extremely far location (figure 3&4), the depot is still in the solution. Theoretically, to minimize the objective function, if there's no constraints about the edges into and out of the depot, then x_0i and x_i0 should always be 0. The constraints  about the depot can be like sum(x_i0 >= 1), but there's no such constraints in the model.

This is the code used for adding constraints:

```
mdl.addConstrs(   # mdl is the name of the model
    quicksum(x[i, j] for j in V if j != i) == 1 for i in N)  # only one edge into customer node i
mdl.addConstrs(
    quicksum(x[i, j] for i in V if i != j) == 1 for j in N)  # only one edge out of customer node i
mdl.addConstrs((x[i, j] == 1) >> (u[i] + q[i] == u[j]) for i, j in A if i != 0 and j != 0)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] >= q[i] for i in N)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] <= Q for i in N)
```

Now I'm confident that my code is not problematic (if anyone want to check it I've put it on my Github: https://github.com/KaiyuWei/VRP-problem-by-Gurobi--Python), then could anyone explain the reason why the depot is always included? Thanks!

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

[image: figure 3]

[image: figure 4]

Comment: You should probably first look into the node with **3** out-going edges (2nd picture). And please include the relevant parts of the code here if debugging is what you need. Don't force people leaving this site to see your code.

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your response. I've posted the code about adding constraints here.

Comment: This question is better suited for the OR stackexchange site: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mattmilten Thank you somuch, it's a good place!